# Weird characters show up

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath, mojibake

I am trying to fetch prices from the steam market, now this all works well, and it is returning an array, but there is one problem. CS:GO items such as StatTrak items or knives have either a star (`★` or how Valve sends it "`\u2605`") or the trademark logo (`™` or how Valve sends it "`\u2122`")

My array doesn't see them as these characters, but convert it to this instead:

`â StatTrakâ¢ Karambit | Damascus Steel (Field-Tested)`

But it should be:

`★ StatTrak™ Karambit | Damascus Steel (Field-Tested)`

This is how I fetch the info:

```
    $url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=0&count=99&&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=price&sort_dir=popular&appid=730&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $html = json_decode($html, true);
    $html = $html['results_html'];

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $itemname = $xpath->query('//span[@id="result_' . $q . '_name"]');
    $itemprice = $xpath->query('//*[@id="result_' . $q . '"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]/span[1]');
```

In an loop, ofcourse, but that shouldn't matter right now. `$q` is in the range 0-99.

How do I go about it getting the contents with the proper characters?

Comment: This seems like a classic case of Mojibake: a character being stored in one encoding and displayed using another one. Make sure your page's character encoding is set correctly. You should probably use UTF-8. You can do this using `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in the `<head>` section of your HTML.

Comment: @DaanWilmer Thanks for your reaction, it has been solved by doing the following: `$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to replace special characters with the original characters.

```
 $itemprice = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>', '<p>&Acirc;&nbsp;</p>', '&amp;quot;', '&Acirc;&nbsp;'), array('', '', '', '', '', '"',''), $dom->saveHTML()));
```

View the page source and check what your original character is replaced with, Then again replace them with the original characters using `str_replace()`.